# Write PySpark dataframe into Partitioned Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am learning Spark. I have a dataframe `ts` of below structure.

```
ts.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|    UTC|                 PST|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|2020-11-04 02:24:...|2020-11-03 18:24:...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to insert `ts` into **Partitioned table in Hive** with below structure,

```
spark.sql(""" create table db.ts_part
(
UTC timestamp,
PST timestamp
)
PARTITIONED BY(  bkup_dt DATE )
STORED AS ORC""")
```

How do i dynamically pass `system run date` in the insert statement so that it gets partitioned on `bkup_dt` in table based on date.

I tried something like this code. But it didn't work

```
ts.write.partitionBy(current_date()).insertInto("db.ts_part",overwrite=False)
```

How should I do it? Can someone please help!

Comment: what did not work ? what is the unexpected behavior or the error code ?

Comment: I got the error - TypeError: Column is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by creating new column with **`current_date()`** and then write as partitioned by hive table.

**`Example:`**

```
df.\
withColumn("bkup_dt",current_date()).\
write.\
partitionBy("bkup_dt").\
insertInto("db.ts_part",overwrite=False)
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

try by **`creating temp view`** then run **`insert`** statement.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

sql("insert into table <table_name> partition (bkup_dt) select *,current_date bkup_dt from tmp")
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this would work. But it's a huge dataframe. Is there any otherway to dynamically pass it instead of adding a column to the dataframe